# MSI install package installs program, but it will not launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, .net-4.5

I'm lost. I have tried Click Once deployment and windows installer as a .msi package. I prefer to use MSI. I have followed several tutorials which all say the same thing, but when followed exactly, my application is installed, appears as it should, but the program will not launch by double clicking icon or right-click and run as administrator.

The process I am following is to add a setup project, add a primary output to the application folder, create a shortcut to primary output in the user's desktop and program menu. Build project. MSI is in bin/Debug or bin/release depending on which was used to build. The MSI file is available.

I double clicked the MSI. Proceed through the wizard and it successfully installs. I see the shortcuts and it is installed, but it will not start. It looks like it tries when double clicked, but then... nothing. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you checked the event log to see if your app is crashing on startup? It's likely it has a dependency which you didn't package into the MSI.

Comment: @slugster DLL files, maybe? I'll check the log now.

Answer (score 3):

When creating the setup project for the MSI, you will have to right click target computer's application folder and hover over "Add" and choose Add Project Output. I needed to add the application's icon, a few DLL files, etc. It allows you to choose which items to include. Many tutorials only show the primary output. You may need to choose more than just the primary output. I included everything but source files and it now works. You may also need to right click, hover on "Add" and choose "File" to add the application icon and any other necessary files. I also had to add a text file. Hope this helps.